# TypeScript 3.1 : How to index an Array with an Enum in strict mode?

Tags: typescript

This code does not compile when TypeScript "strict" mode is enabled due to "noImplicitAny".

Can you tell me how to declare/use Arrays indexed by Enum values ?

```
namespace CommandLineParser {
    enum States { sNoWhere, sSwitchValue }

    abstract class State {        
    }

    class NoWhereState extends State {

    }

    class SwitchValueState extends State {

    }

    export class GetOption {
        state: State;
        states: Array<State>[States];

        constructor() {
            this.states = new Array(2);
            this.states[States.sNoWhere] = new NoWhereState();
            this.states[States.sSwitchValue] = new SwitchValueState();
            this.state = this.states[States.sNoWhere];
        }
    }
}

let go = new CommandLineParser.GetOption();
```

Errors are :

error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'State' has no index signature.

```
          this.states[States.sNoWhere] = new NoWhereState(this);
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'State' has no index signature.

```
          this.states[States.sSwitchValue] = new SwitchValueState(this);
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'State' has no index signature.

```
          this.state = this.states[States.sNoWhere];
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want an array ? An object would work better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the type of `states`. You define an array of `State`, but then you use a type query and the result of that will be `State`. The assignment `this.states = new Array(2);` succeeds because the `State` class has no members, so an array technically satisfies the class signature.

This will work:

```
export class GetOption {
    state: State;
    states: Array<State>;

    constructor() {
        this.states = new Array(2);
        this.states[States.sNoWhere] = new NoWhereState();
        this.states[States.sSwitchValue] = new SwitchValueState();
        this.state = this.states[States.sNoWhere];
    }
}
```

Now this does mean that you can index via any number into the array, not just restricted to the types elements of the enum which might not be what you want. If you don't really need the array methods, a simple object might work better, although you will have have to initialize it all at once (or use a type assertion to make it fit `this.states = {} as any`):

```
export class GetOption {
    state: State;
    states: Record<States, State>;

    constructor() {
        this.states = {
            [States.sNoWhere]: new NoWhereState(),
            [States.sSwitchValue] : new SwitchValueState()
        }
        this.state = this.states[States.sNoWhere];
        this.state = this.states[10]; //error
    }
}
```

A tuple type would work as well since the enum constants correspond to numbers anyway, and you would get `Array` methods on it if you need them:

```
export class GetOption {
    state: State;
    states: [State, State];

    constructor() {
        this.states = [new NoWhereState, new SwitchValueState]
        this.state = this.states[States.sNoWhere];
        this.state = this.states[10]; //error
    }
}
```

Comment: The version with `Record<States, State>` works like a charm ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is kinda old one and not realli answering question, but I found my way way more intuitive to use objects instead of arrays in your case. Consider following:

```
enum MyIndexingEnum { stateOne, stateTwo }
const someIndexedObject {
  [MyIndexingEnum.stateOne]: { /* stuff */ }
  [MyIndexingEnum.stateTwo]: { /* stuff */ }
}

/* Accessing stuff */
someIndexedObject[MyIndexingEnum.stateOne]
```